# How do I store predefined data in ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm creating an **Ionic v3 App**. I've to store some of the predefined data so that my application can use it to render different parts of the app. This data includes:

- JSON
- Images
- Videos

I've found **Ionic Storage**, but I don't think it is what I want.

**What I want to achieve?**

I've a list view (which needs to be fetched from JSON). And when an item is tapped, I need to read the JSON file for that list item and load the content in the next page. This content will include images, text, and even videos.

I don't know where and how to store all this data. Should I just store them inside the **assets** directory? Will this make it available inside APK and iOS build?

Remember: I need all this data locally. Just install the app and done (No internet connection)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store your data within your assets folder and http.get them from there.
Your cordova tools will copy those file so that they will get packaged in your apk/ipa

For your JSON file, your can load it within the ngOnInit inside your app.component.ts and then JSON stringify it in the localStorage.
Then, Where you need to use it, you can parse the JSON string your stored when the app started.

Comment: Mehdi, videos aren't working whenever I emulate the device.The images and JSON data however works. I used <video> to play the video. It works perfectly fine on browser, but in emulator, The video was playing but I could only hear the audio (no picture was there). Please help :(

Comment: Have you tried to install this native plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/